# Appending a div for responsive sites

Tags: jquery

this is a strange one, i am not sure if it can be done.

I would like to remove a div and then put it back, depending of screen size / device type. Take a responsive site for example with ads in a right side column, this column disappears when screen size reaches mobile sizes.

The ad tag code is hard coded on to the page, therefore when in mobile viewing the ad code is still firing. Using a media query wouldn't do the track i don't think, as it would just "hide" the element.

I need it to be removed when the site reaches a certain break point, then gets put back...i have done some research and it seems that the append class could work?

This is my mock up example. - http://mrpbennett.com/addRemove

```
     <div class="adslot-container">
          <img class="mpu"src="img/mpu1.png">
      </div>

      <div class="adslot-container">
          <img class="mpu"src="img/mpu2.png">
      </div>
```

The above is the code / container "adslot-container" will be what i want to remove from the code and put back depending on screen size. Not hide...so the ad code within the container doesn't fire on load.

hope that makes things a little clearer?

Comment: Please post enough code in the question for the specific problem to be reproduced

Comment: adding a class can only also do the same as a media query would - show or hide

Comment: Without seeing the code, the first thing I think of is to just apply `display: none;` for the breakpoints where you want to hide the div.

Comment: I am not sure what you really mean but from what i understand you should use `<div id="main"/> loading... another div as per requirement </div>` with  `width and height`

Comment: Use media queries in CSS. When the screen size drops below the required, set `display: none` on the element. Javascript shouldn't be used as a crutch for the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess you don't want the content loaded or executed at all below a certain resolution making hiding/showing unacceptable.

Something like this could provide a JavaScript solution for dynamically adding the content:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var lastWidth = null;
  $(window).bind('resize', function(e){
      if((lastWidth == null || lastWidth < 500) && window.innerWidth >= 500)
      {
          $('body').append('<div class="target"></div>');
      }
      else if((lastWidth == null || lastWidth >= 500) && window.innerWidth < 500)
      {
          $('.target').remove();
      }

      lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Essentially simulating media queries using the window resize event.

Comment: I have just added a mock up page and a snippet, hope that makes sense.

Comment: @pbennettuk Yes I think that does make sense. What I'm not clear on is how you would "send it down", since you can't just send it as part of the HTML body without it being executed. So you would have to embed it somewhere as a literal string and append it, or perhaps request the content asynchronously or something. The solution I posted should work for adding the content dynamically, but I'm not sure how you intend to actually get the content.

Comment: the content is served into a piece of script, buy an advertiser. So the serving of the content isn't an worry here. Its the removal of the code and making sure it doesn't fire an impression.

I will give your snipper a try and see what happens. thank you.

Comment: @pbennettuk Okay just keep in mind that this works more by adding it only if it's large, rather than removing it if it's small. Since you don't want it to trigger you have to avoid adding it.